# Using Python (in Colab), how to convert a multiband ee.Image into an ee.ImageCollection?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, image, rioxarray, xarray

I ultimately want to convert an ee.Image to an xarray object so I can further process the data.
I know the library `wxee` can do that with `ee.ImageCollection.wx.to_xarray()`. However, it requires an ee.ImageCollection as input and all I have is a multiband ee.Image.

Therefore, I've been trying to convert my multiband ee.Image into an ee.ImageCollection.

Could anyone help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?
Or, if anyone knows another way to directly convert a multiband ee.Image onto an xarray, that would be great too.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
PastureBr = ee.Image('projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection6/mapbiomas_collection60_pasture_quality_v1')
bandnames = PastureBr.bandNames().getInfo()
type(PastureBr) #this gives: ee.image.Image

PastureBr
##This previous line gives:
#Image projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection6/mapbiomas_collection60_pasture_quality_v1 (21 bands)
#type:Image
#id:projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection6/mapbiomas_collection60_pasture_quality_v1
#version:1635171484014985
#bands: List (21 elements)
#properties: Object (2 properties)

scaledbands = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(PastureBr.select(bandnames))
type(scaledbands) #This gives: ee.imagecollection.ImageCollection

PastureBrxr = scaledbands.wx.to_xarray(scale = 20_000,crs = "EPSG:4326")
#The previous line gives the error: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ee/data.py in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
    336   try:
--> 337     return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
    338   except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:

8 frames
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/value:compute?prettyPrint=false&alt=json returned "ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>.
Actual type: Image<[pasture_quality_2000, pasture_quality_2001, pasture_quality_2002, pasture_quality_2003, pasture_quality_2004, pasture_quality_2005, pasture_quality_2006, pasture_quality_2007, pasture_quality_2008, pasture_quality_2009, pasture_quality_2010, pasture_quality_2011, pasture_quality_2012, pasture_quality_2013, pasture_quality_2014, pasture_quality_2015, pasture_quality_2016, pasture_quality_2017, pasture_quality_2018, pasture_quality_2019, pasture_quality_2020]>.". Details: "ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>.
Actual type: Image<[pasture_quality_2000, pasture_quality_2001, pasture_quality_2002, pasture_quality_2003, pasture_quality_2004, pasture_quality_2005, pasture_quality_2006, pasture_quality_2007, pasture_quality_2008, pasture_quality_2009, pasture_quality_2010, pasture_quality_2011, pasture_quality_2012, pasture_quality_2013, pasture_quality_2014, pasture_quality_2015, pasture_quality_2016, pasture_quality_2017, pasture_quality_2018, pasture_quality_2019, pasture_quality_2020]>.">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

EEException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ee/data.py in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
    337     return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
    338   except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
--> 339     raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
    340 
    341 

EEException: ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>.
Actual type: Image<[pasture_quality_2000, pasture_quality_2001, pasture_quality_2002, pasture_quality_2003, pasture_quality_2004, pasture_quality_2005, pasture_quality_2006, pasture_quality_2007, pasture_quality_2008, pasture_quality_2009, pasture_quality_2010, pasture_quality_2011, pasture_quality_2012, pasture_quality_2013, pasture_quality_2014, pasture_quality_2015, pasture_quality_2016, pasture_quality_2017, pasture_quality_2018, pasture_quality_2019, pasture_quality_2020]>.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of images by mapping over the band names and selecting each band, one by one. Then you create a collection from the list of images.

```
collection = ee.ImageCollection(
    PastureBr.bandNames().map(lambda bandName:
      PastureBr
          .select(ee.String(bandName))
          .rename('value') # All images must have the same band name
    )
)
```